# How can I detect reaching the end of a ScrollViewer item (Windows 8)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, scrollviewer

I need to do some work when the user scrolls to the end of a ScrollViewer in a Windows 8 'Metro UI' app that uses .xaml with C# behind-code. Alternatively, the ScrollViewer has snap-points enabled, so detecting a "snapping" event will also work.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can bind your ListView to collection that implements [ISupportIncrementalLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701916).

The extra items will be loaded automatically when there is an empty space to fill.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help: http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-automatically-scrolling-listview-to-bottom-and-detecting-when-listview-is-scrolled

I'm not sure it works when getting back from snapped-mode, haven't tried it yet.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would be helpful - [Add Items to ListBox when scroll reaches the end in Windows phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930533/add-items-to-listbox-when-scroll-reaches-the-end-in-windows-phone)

Not Windows 8 exactly, but still XAML.