# How to detect when ListView Reached to and end in Windows 10 Universal app development

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-10

I followed this link [Detect when WPF listview scrollbar is at the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301411/detect-when-wpf-listview-scrollbar-is-at-the-bottom)
But ScrollBar.Scroll doesn't exist for ListView in Windows 10 .. how to achieve this requirement in windows 10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods described here [How can I detect reaching the end of a ScrollViewer item (Windows 8)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003326/how-can-i-detect-reaching-the-end-of-a-scrollviewer-item-windows-8)

If you want incremental loading there's a built-in solution for that. Otherwise go and traverse the visual tree for the scrollviewer object in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply detecting `VerticalOffset` and `ScrollableHeight` of your `ScrollViewer`. Here is my simple code.

**XAML:**

```
<!--Apply ScrollViwer over the ListView to detect scrolling-->
<ScrollViewer Name="ContentCommentScroll" Grid.Row="2"
              ViewChanged="ContentCommentScroll_ViewChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

                <!--My Dynamic ListView-->
               <ListView Name="MyDataList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" 
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"
                            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**And code in its `XAML.CS:`**

```
// Hold ScrollViwer
public ScrollViewer listScrollviewer = new ScrollViewer();

// Binded event, which will trigger on scrolling of ScrollViewer
private void ContentCommentScroll_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Scrolling(ContentCommentScroll);
}

private void Scrolling(DependencyObject depObj)
{
    ScrollViewer myScroll= GetScrollViewer(depObj);

    // Detecting if ScrollViewer is fully vertically scrolled or not
    if (myScroll.VerticalOffset ==  myScroll.ScrollableHeight)
    {
        // ListView reached at of its end, when you are scrolling it vertically.
        // Do your work here here 
    }
}

public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
{
    if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can also apply similar logic to detect that if `ListView` `Horizontally` reached to its end.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap it with a ScrollViewer and name it. Then you can use some other methods.